# ¿Como desagrupar un json cuando tiene la misma clave?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, json

Tengo la consulta MySql

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(MONTH(inv_date), "-", YEAR(inv_date)) AS month_year,
    MONTH(inv_date) AS month_number,
    brch_id,
    brch_code,
    brch_name,
    SUM(inv_total) AS total_month_branch
FROM
    invoice_master
        INNER JOIN
    ctrl_branches ON inv_branch = brch_id
WHERE
    inv_status != 'Anulada'
        AND inv_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE,
        INTERVAL 11 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY MONTH(inv_date) , brch_id
ORDER BY inv_date
```

El resultado es las ventas por establecimiento de los ultimos 12 meses asi:

```
month_year  brch_code   total_month_branch
7-2019      OFI1        9939255.00
8-2019      OFI1        22260118.50
9-2019      OFI1        165832787.00
10-2019     OFI1        186330944.36
10-2019     POS2        1850550.00
11-2019     POS2        14889335.00
11-2019     OFI1        6927673.96
```

en php armo el array asi

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $total_branch[] = [ 
        "month-year" => $row['month_year'],
        $row['brch_code'] => $row['total_month_branch'], 
    ];
}
echo json_encode($total_branch);
```

El resultado es un JSON

```
{"month-year":"7-2019","OFI1":"9939255.00"},
{"month-year":"8-2019","OFI1":"22260118.50"},
{"month-year":"9-2019","OFI1":"165832787.00"},
{"month-year":"10-2019","OFI1":"188181494.36"},
{"month-year":"11-2019","POS2":"21817008.96"}
```

Como ven en los meses 10-2019 y 11-2019 hay ventas en OFI1 Y POS2 y en el JSON solo llega el dato de OFI1 Y POS2 respectivamente, deberia quedar asi

```
{"month-year":"7-2019","OFI1":"9939255.00"},
{"month-year":"8-2019","OFI1":"22260118.50"},
{"month-year":"9-2019","OFI1":"165832787.00"},
{"month-year":"10-2019","OFI1":"188181494.36","POS2":"1850550.00"},
{"month-year":"11-2019","POS2":"21817008.96","OFI1":"6927673.96"}
```

Y de haber mas establecimientos quedarian al lado de los demas, esto lo necesito para pasarselo a un generador de charts... por lo tanto solo esta mostrando una sola barra en todos los meses, no se si la consulta esta mal planteada o si estoy armando mal el JSON.

Comment: gbianchi, al editar el titulo de la pregunta confundes a quienes responden, desagrupar JSON no es lo que necesito...

Comment: El `JSON` que publicas como resultado del código `PHP` no es correcto [acá la demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e7c7d52ca54f760285859823e374b98d0c31e1aa)

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo con @Marcos. De igual forma respondí con la solución

Comment: @Marcos, efectivamente, el 'JSON' que publico como resultado del código ´PHP´ no es el que necesito, el tuyo es el resultado que necesito pero de donde  obtienes los valores de ´$rows[]´?

Comment: La opcion de pasar el array por el constructor ´foreach´ como lo sugiere @Marcos es la mas adecuada

Comment: @JuanCarlos, `$rows` es el equivalente a todos los resultados de la consulta que publicas. Una forma de obtenerlo sería haciendo haciendo `$result = $mysqli->query($query); $rows = $result->fetch_all(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`, donde `$query` sería la cadena de la consulta. Si realmente estas obteniendo como resultado el `JSON` lo que publicas, entonces, lo que esta mal son los datos que crees que devuelve la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitarías hacer algo así:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $key = array_search($row['month_year'], array_column($total_branch, 'month-year')); // Buscas si el mes ya existe en el array

    if(is_numeric($key)){ // Si existe le agregas un objeto mas 

        $total_branch[$key][$row['brch_code']] = $row['total_month_branch'];

    }else{ // Si no existe lo creas

        $total_branch[] = [ 
            "month-year" => $row['month_year'],
            $row['brch_code'] => $row['total_month_branch'], 
        ];

    }


}
```